Full Calendar React: How can we customize / override the CSS class in a React version of full calendar
I'm using an React Full Calendar example,  that was shared as a part of the example in the Full Calendar documentation (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-examples/tree/main/react17).
I am using the code base of  react-17 for reference, I wanted to customize/override some of the CSS classes. Requirements:

I want to display the date label of a calender cell, to be on the top left corner of each cell.
I want to show week number as a separate columns as shown in the below image /  screenshot.

Expectation:

In the index.css file I added the following code:
.fc { /* the calendar root */
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;


  .fc-daygrid-day-top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row **!important;**
  }
}

so in the actual code 'flex-direction' was set to 'row-reverse' and I modified it to 'row' to display the cell values in top left of the cell, but to get this to work I had to add the !important 'specificity' to get this to work, but this would be a temporary work around, so is there a way to makie this to work without adding '!imporatant' and I wanted the week number to be shown as a separate columns, any pointers for this.
BAsically I wanted to oevrride the css classes of react version full calendar, If there are some example or if someone can point me to the right documentation it would be of great help.

If your own rules come "after" the ones already defined by the component itself, then they would overwrite the formatting even with the same specificity. ("After" here meaning, in the final result - whether that is the order in which several separate stylesheets are embedded, or in which they are all combined by some packer into one single stylesheet, does not matter.) And if you can't guarantee that - then increase the specificity of your own rules.

For reference, in case you haven't seen it: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customization
